# Laravel 5.4: One to Many with One to One

Tags: laravel, one-to-many

I  created one to one relationship where user belongs to town, so in User model I have:

```
public function town()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Town');
}
```

and in users table I have town_id column. So, when user post something it says that user is from that town. That works.

Now, I created Settlement model which in same way belongs to App\Town (many users can come with one town), so again when settlement is created with some user it displays town of user and settlement which also contain town_id as that user table. (I hope I'm not confusing)

Question: When user is logged in, how to display settlements from his town only?

This is my code until now:

AdminSettlementsController:

```
public function index()
{
    $settlements = Settlement::paginate(10);
    $towns = Auth::user()->town->id;
    $town[$towns] = Auth::user()->town->name;
    $reon = Reon::pluck('name', 'id')->all();

    return view('admin.settlements.index', compact('settlements', 'town', 'reon'));
}
```

User model has this:

```
public function town()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Town');
}
```

and index.blade.php in settlements folder has this table:

```
@if ($settlements)
    @foreach ($settlements as $settlement)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $settlement->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $settlement->town->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $settlement->reon->name }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('settlements.edit', $settlement->id) }}">{{ $settlement->name }}</a></td>
          </tr> 
    @endforeach 
@endif
```

I presume that in Town model I need to have settlements() method where that method hasMany App\Settlement but I don't know how to go from there.

I hope my english is not too bad. Thanks

Comment: You can do Settlement::where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)->paginate(10);

Comment: I think that this solve the problem. Thank you, Kasijus.